# Horizontal scroll bars on programmatic dojox.grid.DataGrid

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

How can I keep the horizontal scroll bar from displaying?

An example of what I am attempting is at http://jsfiddle.net/fdlane/gjkGF/3/

Below is an example page of what I am attempting to do.  With the width of the container div set to greater than the grid width, I was expecting that the horizontal scroll bars would not be displayed.

Using the current height of 200px and with the number of rows greater than 6, the vertical is displayed (good).  However, the horizontal is then also displayed (bad).

What am I missing?

Thanks

fdl

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Style" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Style" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dojox/grid/resources/tundraGrid.css">
<title>Grid Scrolling</title>
</head>
<body class="tundra">
<div id="container" style="width: 350px; height: 200px">
    <div id="myGrid">
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dojo/dojo.xd.js">    </script>
<script>
    dojo.require("dojo.store.Memory");
    dojo.require("dojo.data.ObjectStore");
    dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");

    dojo.ready(function () {

        var myStore = new dojo.store.Memory({
            data: [{ id: "RecId1", values: "fooValue1" },
            { id: "RecId2", values: "fooValue2" },
            { id: "RecId3", values: "fooValue3" },
            { id: "RecId4", values: "fooValue4" },
            { id: "RecId5", values: "fooValue5" },
            { id: "RecId6", values: "fooValue6" },
            { id: "RecId7", values: "fooValue7" },
            { id: "RecId7", values: "fooValue7"}]
        });

        dataStore = new dojo.data.ObjectStore({
            objectStore: myStore
        });

        var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({

            store: dataStore,
            structure: [{
                name: "ID",
                field: "id",
                width: "100px"
            }, {
                name: "Values",
                field: "values",
                width: "100px"
            }]
        }, "myGrid");

        grid.startup();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this style override to your head element:

```
<style>
  .dojoxGridScrollbox { overflow-x: hidden; }
</style>
```

Reason may very well be, that when the grid overflows vertically, the vertical (-y) scroller appears and consumes 30 ( or so ) pixels of width, making the grid container also overflow in horizontal orientation

You can try to make use of the grid resize function - if a borderlayout.resize fixes your issue, reason is that it recursively resizes its children (at some calculated abs value). With Grid, you'd see this flow:

```
            resize: function(changeSize, resultSize){
                    // summary:
                    //              Update the grid's rendering dimensions and resize it

                    // Calling sizeChange calls update() which calls _resize...so let's
                    // save our input values, if any, and use them there when it gets
                    // called.  This saves us an extra call to _resize(), which can
                    // get kind of heavy.

                    // fixes #11101, should ignore resize when in autoheight mode(IE) to avoid a deadlock
                    // e.g when an autoheight editable grid put in dijit.form.Form or other similar containers,
                    // grid switch to editing mode --> grid height change --> From height change
                    // ---> Form call grid.resize() ---> grid height change  --> deaklock
                    if(dojo.isIE && !changeSize && !resultSize && this._autoHeight){
                            return;
                    }
                    this._pendingChangeSize = changeSize;
                    this._pendingResultSize = resultSize;
                    this.sizeChange();
            },
```

Comment: Thank you.  This worked.  I just thought I was creating the grid wrong or calling startup wrong because the grid (as sized) should not have the  horizontal scroll.  Further attempts showed that if I put the grid in the center pane of a full-page bordercontainer, then on initial page load the horizontal scroll is displayed, but then any resizing of the browser window causes the scroll to disappear. Of course, this attempt was done before I added the style you recommended.  must have something to do with when .resize() is firing.  Thanks again for your help.  fdl

Comment: idd youre right, a bordercontainer layout calls resize on all of its children when resized - if child has any such functionality

Comment: I just wish I understood how to make the resize that happens on the initial page load correctly hide the horizontal scroll.  The resize that is firing after the page is loaded and then the user changes the browser window does correctly hide the horizontal.

Comment: check out this file: /dojo-release-1.7.2-src/dojox/grid/_Grid.js:685

Comment: this seems smelly, but I added  
    setTimeout(function () {
             grid.resize();
            }, 1);  

after the grid is rendered, the horizontal then becomes hidden.  Thank you again for your help.